# Everytime I press a button the website lags even more?(SignalR,Ajax,SQLconenction)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, signalr, sqlconnection

So, i made a dashboard that uses ajax,sqlconnection to sqlserver 2008 and SignalR for realtime data.
Here is an example of the ajax i made that is in a javascript method which is called by the button:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var totalLabel = [];                    
                var totalValue = [];
                var totalLabel2 = [];
                var totalValue2 = [];
                var cityValue = [];
                var cityValue2 = [];
                var cityName = [];
                var numIndex = [];
                var barColor = "";
                var cityString = "";
                for (var j = 1; j < cityList.length; j++)
                {
                    cityString = cityString + "||" + " data[i].Names==\"" + cityList[j] + "\"";
                }    
                cityString = "data[i].Names==\"" + cityList[0] + "\""+cityString;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    totalLabel.push(data[i].Names);
                    totalValue.push(data[i].ValuesDouble);
                    totalLabel2.push(data[i].Names2);
                    totalValue2.push(data[i].ValuesDouble2);
                    //alert(cityString);
                    if (eval(cityString)) {
                        numIndex.push(i);
                    }

                }
                for (var k = 0; k < numIndex.length; k++) {
                    cityValue.push(data[numIndex[k]].ValuesDouble);
                    cityValue2.push(data[numIndex[k]].ValuesDouble2);
                    cityName.push(data[numIndex[k]].Names);
                }
                if (numIndex.length > 0) {
                    for (var h = 0; h < numIndex.length - 1; h++) {
                        barColor = barColor + "{y:" + cityValue2[h] + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(cityValue2[h], cityValue[h]) + "'}" + ",";
                    }
                    barColor = "[" + barColor + "{y:" + cityValue2[numIndex.length-1] + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(cityValue2[numIndex.length-1],cityValue[numIndex.length-1]) + "'}" + "]";
                }
                else {
                    barColor = "[" + barColor + "{y:" + data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble2 + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble2, data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble) + "'}" + "]";
                }

                $(function () {
                    Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><div>__________________________</div><hr>';

                                $.each(this.points, function () {
                                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                });

                                return s;
                            },
                            shared: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: cityName,

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            tickInterval: 500,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            reversed: false,
                            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Daily Schedule',
                            data: eval(barColor)
                        },
                       {
                           name: 'Actual Delivery',
                           data: cityValue,
                           color: '#33FF66'
                       },
                       {
                           name: '0%-69%',
                           //data: cityValue,
                           color: '#FF3366'
                       },
                        {
                            name: '70%-89%',
                           // data: cityValue,
                            color: '#FFCC33'
                        },
                       {
                           name: '90%-100%',
                          // data: cityValue,
                           color: '#003DF5'
                       }]
                    });
                });


            }
        })
```

and here is the example of my Repository to connect to the SQL Server:

```
public class LocationInfoRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<LocationInfo> GetData()
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"
                    SELECT ...  ", connection))
            {

                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                { connection.Open(); }

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()

                        {
                            Names = x.GetString(2),
                            Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(3), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble = x.GetDouble(3),
                            Values2 = Math.Round(x.GetDecimal(4), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble2 = x.GetDecimal(4)

                        }).ToList();

                }
                /*
                using (var reader2 = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader2.NextResult();
                    return reader2.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()

                    {
                        SumVol = x.GetString(0)


                    }).ToList();

                }*/

            }

        }
    }
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyHub.Show();
    }

}
```

I dont know why every time i click a button that calls the ajax, the dashboard lags even more.Is it the ajax, or the sqlconnection,or even signalR itself.Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like a client side performance issue. What is your data.length ?

Comment: my data.length is only about 35. I iterate it 3 times though to get 3 graphs @KobyDouek

Comment: Did you try looking at your client resources (RAM, CPU) ? Also have you tried Developer tools in Chrome (F12) - Network tab, to see where the lag is coming from ?

Comment: I have Pentium DualCore CPU 3.2ghz and 8gb of RAM and im only allowed to use IE in my workplace @KobyDouek

Comment: Which IE version ?

Comment: You have developer tools in IE 11. Check the networking and the client side performance to see where the lag comes from.

Comment: Any hints of what the lag indications are? @KobyDouek

Comment: Under the Networking tab you should see both client ans server side operations. Click your button a few times and try seeing which of the network elements takes increasing time from refresh to refresh

Comment: Also, I would change all your variable declarations globally and not under the "success" method, this will create less resources in your page each refresh. (var totalLabel = [];                    
                var totalValue = [];
...

Comment: So, I have moved the variables outside, and it seems that everytime i press the button, the network keeps GET - ing non stop, how do i stop it? @KobyDouek